# Google Maps: Map Type (Roadmap, Terrain)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I just came across the following web site and noticed they had 2 map types I'm not certain on how to activitate from the Google Maps JavaScript API.

http://www.maps-for-free.com/index.html

It's the "Relief" and "OSM" Map Type as found on the link above.

Any ideas what the API call is to display "Relief" and "OSM" from a Google Map?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard Google Maps API map, it is a layer added by the website. There are relief layers out there you can download and implement yourself actually the website you showed is offering this service.

Comment: +1... Correct. The OP may want to check out Map Tiler (http://www.maptiler.org/) for an open source tool to create map layers over Google Maps.